# run workbook open event from workbook saved with new name

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which uses the saveas dialog to create and open a new workbook based on certain criteria which works perfectly however the newly created workbook does not execute the workbook.open event which opens a userform.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a workbook in code will not cause the auto-open event to run. You need to add the line:

```
wb.RunAutoMacros xlAutoOpen
```

... to your code, assuming wb is the workbook you just opened.